Is Pinescript run on the server or client?
What sort of technology is being used to run pinescript code on TradingView? Is it run on the server side? or is run on the client side?
Are they using webassembly, or is it being run on a like computing networks in the cloud?

I believe it  relies primarily on JavaScript for client-side execution of scripts, although obviously there is some backend stuff going on too.  Couldn't find any information indicating that WebAssembly was used for Pinescript.
